# how check if a job has exhausted all retries

Tags: php, laravel

so lets say i have an entity that invokes some job

like when a payment is done i want to generate a pdf card for that payment
so

```
$payment = Payment::create([....]);
PaymentJob::dispatch($payment);
```

if this job fails or succeeds i want to attach a status (i have PaymentStatus model ) to that payment

so in my job i have something like

```
 public function handle()
 {
    // generate pdf 
    $pyament->Status()->create(['status'=>'success']);
 }
 
 public function failed(Throwable $exception)
 {
    $pyament->Status()->create(['status'=>'error']);
 }
```

the problem is each payment should only have 1 status success or error

if i have 3 retries for each job in my queue setting
and for a job first 2 fails and last one succeed i will have 3 different status for that payment

basically i want my failed status only to be created if all 3 tries have failed and job is not being processed anymore

Comment: Check the retry number in the fail function. It should be in the job object just like your try 3 times is. Also check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#job-chaining

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, with a different approach is to make a column on that `Payment model` and that increment the errors count and then save status  like this example:

```
class PaymentJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 3;
    protected $payment;

    public function __construct(Payment $payment)
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // generate pdf 
        $this->payment->status = 'success';
        $this->payment->save();
    }

    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        $this->payment->increment('retry_count');
        if ($this->attempts() == $this->tries) {
            $this->payment->status = 'error';
            $this->payment->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Check docs for more info on [`failed()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs) and [`$tries`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#max-attempts).